# why doesn't the compiled css file appear?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

i cant understand why  the compiled css file doesn't appear, i checked some videos,but cannot find the mistake,please help,my code is below,also i have pics

```
let gulp = require ('gulp');
let sass = require ('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
```

here is the pictures
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCytp.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHUIA.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP1lx.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGK0h.png

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows in picture 2 you need to set a default sass compiler. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) for more examples

1. Install sass. `npm install sass`
2. Set default compiler `let sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));`

Result:

````
```
let gulp = require ('gulp');
let sass = require ('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
});
````

Comment: thank you very much, i was trying to do this 2 hours, now it is working